# Google Chrome Silverlight Performance Is Significantly Slow

Tags: performance, silverlight, internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser

Chrome Silverlight rendering is very slow (estimation: 10 times slower) comparing to firefox and internet explorer.
You can test this simply using following sample code. Sample code demonstrates 15000 random data rendering inside a data grid.

Do you have any opinion why this is happening? 
There are 2 speculations came to my mind.

1. Google does not want Microsoft's Silverlight gather wide usage on their platform.
2. Chrome's infrastructure somehow causes plugin rendering slow.

XAML part:

```
<UserControl x:Class="sample.view.MemberView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"    
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:sample.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodel:MemberViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <data:DataGrid BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="GSM" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding MobilePhone}"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="BirthDate" Width="2*" Binding="{Binding BirthDate}}"/>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Get Random Data" Width="120" Height="25" Margin="5" Command="{Binding GetRandomDataCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# Part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Browser;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace sample.ViewModel
{
    public class MemberModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class MemberViewModel
    {
        private List<MemberModel> _members;
        public List<MemberModel> Members
        {
            get
            {
                return _members;
            }
            set
            {
                _members = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Members"));
            }
        }
        public MyCommand GetRandomDataCommand { get; set; }

        public MemberViewModel()
        {
            GetRandomDataCommand = new MyCommand();
        }
    }

    public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        private static Random random = new Random();
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            List<MemberModel> members = new List<MemberModel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15000; ++i)
            {
                MemberModel m = new MemberModel();
                m.FirstName = GetRandomString(random.Next(5) + 4);
                m.LastName = GetRandomString(random.Next(5) + 4);
                m.Email = GetRandomString(random.Next(10) + 4);
                m.MobilePhone = GetRandomString(random.Next(12));
                m.BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-random.Next(50) - 18).AddMonths(random.Next(12)).AddDays(random.Next(30));
                members.Add(m);
            }
        }

        private string GetRandomString(int length)
        {
            StringBuilder srb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                srb.Append((char)(65 + random.Next(29));
            }
            return srb.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Merhaba,

A couple of days ago I encountered a msdn page. It says for Silverlight support x64 just for IE. Safari and Chrome browsers supported as x86. As a result of that you are right.
Beside this AFAIK firefox has not a x64 setup.

But for Silverlight 5 things may changed.

I offer IE, Microsoft also :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Google does not want Microsoft's Silverlight gather wide usage on their platform.
   **A:** From my experience, this is not a problem on Google side. I had same problem as you describe for a couple weeks before I sent an email to Microsoft support and they suggested me to use IE. They did not answer me why it works so slow on Chrome.
2. Chrome's infrastructure somehow causes plugin rendering slow.
   **A:** Again, this is not true at all. This problem comes from Microsoft. It seems like it does not care about Silverlight anymore. We plan to move our product to ASP.NET MVC for this reason too.

Comment: You are quite certain about this problem comes from Microsoft!While it is working at the same speed between Ie and Firefox, they made what mistake or change to Chrome?Are they jealous of its speed?I don't think so.Silverlight is using hearth of Windows 8 which is called XAML. Who says Microsoft will not support Silverlight anymore. It is just a speculation which Microsoft doesn't care at all.Finally,If you are planning to move from something to another, one may expect they are same kind of things.Silverlight and ASP.NET MVC do not stand for same purpose. You may refer to HTML/CSS + Javascript.

Comment: Silverlight works with same speed and performance on IE and Firefox? I don't think so. I have tested with a single page with a couple hundreds TextBoxes on it and the page always loads faster on IE (on our machines.)

Comment: Using Silverlight 5 and using sample code above upto 75000 rows I have tested datagrid and the result is: Firefox has no performance difference that I can observe.